# Django ForeignKey _set on an inherited model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models `Category` and `Entry`. There is another model `ExtEntry` that inherits from `Entry`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField('description', blank=True)
    ...

class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=255)    
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    ...

class ExtEntry(Entry):    
    groups= models.CharField('title', max_length=255)
    value= models.CharField('title', max_length=255)
    ...
```

I am able to use the `Category.entry_set` but I want to be able to do `Category.blogentry_set` but it is not available. If this is not available,then I need another method to get all `ExtEntry`related to one particular `Category`

EDIT
My end goal is to have a QuerySet of ExtEntry objects

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need another method to get all ExtEntryrelated to one particular Category

Easy:

```
ExtEntry.objects.filter(categories=my_category)
```

---

> Do you know if there is a way to use the _set feature of an inherited

I don't know if there is a direct they for that. It is not mentioned in documentation.

But it is possible to get similar results with the `select_related`.

```
for e in category.entry_set.select_related('extentry'):
    e.extentry # already loaded because of `select_related`, 
               # however might be None if there is no Extentry for current e
```

It is possible to select only entries which has ExtEntry:

```
for e in category.entry_set.select_related('extentry').exlude(extentry=None):
    e.extentry # now this definitely is something, not None
```

Bad thing about the exclude is that it generates terrybly inefficient query:

```
SELECT entry.*, extentry.* FROM entry
LEFT OUTER JOIN `extentry` ON (entry.id = extentry.entry_ptr_id) 
WHERE NOT (entry.id IN (SELECT U0.id FROM entry U0 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                        extentry U1 ON (U0.id = U1.entry_ptr_id) 
                        WHERE U1.entry_ptr_id IS NULL))
```

So my resume would be: use `ExtEntry.objects.filter()` to get your results. The backwards relations (object.something_set) is just a convenience and does not work in every situation.

Comment: Thanks! this does solve my problem. Do you know if there is a way to use the _set feature of an inherited model?

Comment: if there is a foreign key relationship, you can use model.ForeignKeyModel_set to return records with that relationship

Comment: The only issue with this is that it returns type Entry not ExtEntry therefor not having (direct) access to the extra attributes of the ExtEntry model. Sorry for being picky lol, I really appreciate the help!!

Comment: "The backwards relations (object.something_set) is just a convenience and does not work in every situation" is a great answer. Thankyou (and everyone else) for the answers and comments

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) for an explanation of how this works.

Basically, since you can get the parent model item, you should be able to get its child because an implicit one-to-one linkage is created.

> The inheritance relationship introduces links between the child model and each of its parents (via an automatically-created OneToOneField).

So, you should be able to do:

```
categories = Category.objects.all()
for c in categories:
    entries = c.entry_set.all()
    for e in entries:
        extentry = e.extentry
        print extentry.value
```

It isn't documented that I can see, but I believe that generally, your one-to-one field name will be a lower class version of the inheriting model name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Very detailed and helpful. I can see how you are approaching it, my issues is that I need to return the whole set. And if I have 10,000 Entry but 3 ExtEntry, thats alot of loops to find 3 entries... But this would definitely work

Comment: Indeed. I've shown for all categories but remember if it's only a specific category, definitely dump the outer loop. I'm inclined to think if you only need three ExtEntry objects vs 1000 objects, why not just have fields in Entry with `blank=True`?

Comment: that example was a little extreme, im sure how many of each I will have. even if it was 10,000 v 5000 (all in the same category) its still extra processing...maybe I will just have to cop ti and go with that method...

Answer (score 0):

The problem your running into is because `Entry` and `ExtEntry` are in separate tables. This may be the best solution for you, but you should be aware of that when you choose to use multi-table inheritance.

Something like `category.entry_set.exclude(extentry=None)` should work for you.