# Django and <relatedmodelname>_set method

Tags: python, django

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856887/django-foreignkey-set-on-an-inherited-model) you can see that Django creates lowercasemodelname_set method for ManyToMany relation. Same Django make for Foreign Key (see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEsQFjAF&url=http://blog.lowkster.com/2008/01/getting-to-pesky-foreign-key-data-in.html&ei=YymvUZqxM6m34ATO-IAg&usg=AFQjCNG3AW-fdnZo1UH0XBu69T_KkFVZew&sig2=Ln-LeJq_yCJcsXn55l-ghQ&bvm=bv.47380653,d.bGE&cad=rja) for example).
Could somebody point to documentation on this, or just tell about what this method serve for?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is quite comprehensive, and can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).